# Prove that $a_{n}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{2^j}{j} $ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that

$a_{n}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{2^j}{j} $

is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n = (n+1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j\cdot2^{n+1-j}}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{k}{n+1}\right)2^k} $$
by the dominated convergence theorem approaches
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^k}=\color{red}{1} $$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{x^j}{j}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {x^j}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}-x^n$$

or as an alternative by Stolz-Cesaro

$$ \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{2^j}{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{2^j}{j}}{\frac{2^{n+2}}{n+2}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}= \frac{\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}{\frac{2^{n+2}}{n+2}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1}}$$

Comment: But we can not use integral :(

Comment: @math.trouble Stolz-Cesaro?

Comment: We can only use the monotone convergence theorem. I've showed that $  a_{n} $ is monotonic