# Can you please tell me about convergence of the sequence $X_n=\frac{\left(n+1\right)}{2^{n+1}}\sum _{x=1}^n\frac{2^x}{x}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What can we say about convergence of a sequence whose $n$-th term $X_n$ is as follows?
$$\frac{\left(n+1\right)}{2^{n+1}}\sum _{x=1}^n\frac{2^x}{x}$$
I have tried to compute limit, apply ratio test and Sandwich theorem, I also tried to use the property monotonic bounded sequences are convergent but I am unable to come up with a solution.

Comment: what can you say? That is, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: (See also: [Prove that $a_{n}=\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{2^j}{j} $ is convergent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2976307)).